# Using rectangle in Matlab. Using Sum()

Tags: matlab, sum, rectangles

I have performed rgb2gray on an image and did a sobel edge detection on the image. 
then did

```
faceEdges = faceNoNoise(:,:) > 50;        %binary threshold
```

so it sets the outline of the image (a picture of a face), to black and white. Values 1 is white pixel, and 0 is black pixel. Someone said I could use this,

```
mouthsquare = rectangle('position',[recX-mouthBoxBuffer, recY-mouthBoxBuffer, recXDiff*2+mouthBoxBuffer/2, recYDiff*2+mouthBoxBuffer/2],...   % see the change in coordinates
      'edgecolor','r');
numWhite = sum(sum(mouthsquare));
```

He said to use two sum()'s because it gets the columns and rows of the contained pixels within the rectangle. numWhite always returns 178 and some decimal numbers.

Comment: So, what's the question? :-)

Comment: im sorry, its not returning a true value of how many white pixels are in the rectangle. Is there any way to see how many white pixels are in the rectangle? Besides writing a for loop within a for loop and checking every pixle my self and incrementing a number by 1 everytime its a white pixel?

Comment: Just saying, maybe it's a good idea for you to edit your post and add there the question too. It will increase the chances that someone will figure out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 2D matrix `M` (this being -- for exmple -- an image), the way to count how many elements have the value 1 is:

```
count_1 = sum(M(:)==1)
```

or

```
count_1 = sum(reshape(M,1,[])==1)
```

If the target values are not **exactly** 1, but have a Δ-threshold of, let's say, +/- 0.02, then one should ask for:

```
count_1_pm02 = sum((M(:)>=0.98) & (M(:)<=1.02))
```

or the equivalent using reshape.